# Add two options to select list top and bottom using ng-options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to populate a drop down list in a `cshtml` page using Angular.  The Angular `controller` calls a service using `Web API` to return values.  I have added a default selected item to instruct users to select an item from the list.  I also want to append 'Other' to the end of the select list.

I prefer to use the `ng-options` if I can.  I know how to do this using `ng-repeat.`

The markup is as follows:

```
<div class="formElement">
  <label for="companySelect" class="required long">{{'CompanyName'}}</label>
  <select name="companySelect" id="companySelect" ng-change="selectCompany()" ng-model="data" data-ng-options="company.CompanyName 
    for company indata.companySelect | orderBy:'CompanyName' track by company.CompanyName">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value ="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the json response?

Comment: why can't you push `other` to your data?

Comment: You can push 'other' in your data when you receive your data in service layer or controller layer.

Comment: Right, but if you'll notice, the list is alphabetized.  If I add other at the service layer, it appears in the middle of the list.  Not desirable behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if your webapi return some json data, you got that values by `$scope.company` in your angular controller

- Add `Please Select` to top element of your array

You can do it by using array [unshift](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

```
$scope.company.unshift("Please Select")// May it be a object
```

- Add `Others` to bottom element of your array

You can do it by using array [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

```
$scope.company.push("Other")// May it be a object
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't account for the fact that the list is sorted in the html.  Your solution results in "Other" being in the middle of the list.

Comment: However, I didn't know about the unshift method and definitely will use this, so points for that and I marked it as answer.

Comment: `unshift` method saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by sorting the data in the Web Api, then adding a new company type with the name other at the end.  This kept the list in sorted order and provided me with other.  I was hoping to find a simple solution within AngularJS, but the solutions offered don't account for the need to have a sorted list.  Thanks for the suggestions, and I realize that I did not call out that the list was sorted, but it is easily seen in the html that I posted.